# Searching Record List using single parameter Id and compare with multiple columns EF

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to fetch records from table but I have single parameter Id. I want to compare that single parameter with multiple columns. Here is my code.

```
var list = _ctx.Scheduler.Where(x => x.SaloonId == Id).ToList().Select(x => new AppointmentListModel
            {
                Id = x.ID,
                StatusName = x.AppointmentStatus.StatusName,
                AppointmentDate = x.AppointmentDate.ToShortDateString(),
                AppointmentDay = x.AppointmentDay,
                CustomerName = x.CustomerDetail.UserMaster.FirstName + " " + x.CustomerDetail.UserMaster.LastName,
                FromTime = x.AppointmentTimeFrom,
                ToTime = x.AppointmentTimeTo
            }).ToList();
```

The above query is to get appointments from scheduler table on saloon Id. Here is the next query which is used to get record from same table but compare with customerId.

```
var list = _ctx.Scheduler.Where(x => x.CustomerId == Id).ToList().Select(x => new AppointmentListModel
            {
                Id = x.ID,
                StatusName = x.AppointmentStatus.StatusName,
                AppointmentDate = x.AppointmentDate.ToShortDateString(),
                AppointmentDay = x.AppointmentDay,
                CustomerName = x.CustomerDetail.UserMaster.FirstName + " " + x.CustomerDetail.UserMaster.LastName,
                FromTime = x.AppointmentTimeFrom,
                ToTime = x.AppointmentTimeTo
            }).ToList();
```

How to achieve this by using single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [conditional logical OR (`||`) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-):

```
var list = _ctx.Scheduler
    .Where(x => x.SaloonId == Id || x.CustomerId == Id)
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new AppointmentListModel
            {
                Id = x.ID,
                StatusName = x.AppointmentStatus.StatusName,
                AppointmentDate = x.AppointmentDate.ToShortDateString(),
                AppointmentDay = x.AppointmentDay,
                CustomerName = x.CustomerDetail.UserMaster.FirstName + " " + x.CustomerDetail.UserMaster.LastName,
                FromTime = x.AppointmentTimeFrom,
                ToTime = x.AppointmentTimeTo
            })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What If I have saloonId and CustomerId same?

Comment: @MuhammadKamran it will be included into the list, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add both conditions to Where clause.

```
    var list = _ctx.Scheduler.Where(x => x.SaloonId == Id || x.CustomerId == Id).ToList().Select(x => new AppointmentListModel
        {
            Id = x.ID,
            StatusName = x.AppointmentStatus.StatusName,
            AppointmentDate = x.AppointmentDate.ToShortDateString(),
            AppointmentDay = x.AppointmentDay,
            CustomerName = x.CustomerDetail.UserMaster.FirstName + " " + x.CustomerDetail.UserMaster.LastName,
            FromTime = x.AppointmentTimeFrom,
            ToTime = x.AppointmentTimeTo
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: What If I have saloonId and CustomerId same?

Comment: Record will be returned if any of the conditions will match. In this case both return true, but it doesn't affect the result anyhow.